# Why was this user banned from chat?

Tags: support, chat, account-suspension

Recently I discovered a user that I talked to a lot was banned for a little over 300 days. It seemed strange, so I looked into it myself. I found this [chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45792444#45792444):

> You're suspended on Stack Overflow. You should probably not be chatting in SO rooms.
>   You may consider that a formal warning.

He was warned by a mod he shouldn't talk on Stack Overflow chat because he was suspended on Stack Overflow. If you read a little further, you can see he complies and leaves.

However, he told me (through other means) that that was the reason for the ban. It seems to be a harsh and uncalled ban, since he complied with the warning. I seen no evidence of him talking on Stack Overflow chat after the issue. So, out of curiosity and wanting to correct a possible mistake, **why was the user actually banned?**

Comment: FYI the user [posted about their suspension here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309435/why-was-my-account-suspended-for-invalid-reasons).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog no. That's the SO suspension. The SE chat suspension came later

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [rule violations](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9693342/freezephoenix).

Details of a suspension are kept private between the ♦ moderators and the user; if the user decides to disclose/discuss this in public, that's fine, but otherwise the information is not made public.

That's a *site* ban, not a chat ban; [@ArtOfCode](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/72535?m=45792669#45792669) explains:

> It's technically possible because of the chat server trifurcation and because of how chat parents work, but if you're suspended from a site then that's you being asked to take a break from that community for a while - all parts of that community, including chat.

Comment: Could you possible be thinking of the wrong profile? The OP is talking about SE chat, not SO main.

Comment: That's a SO chatroom on the SE chat server. In spirit, it's part of the SO community.

Comment: Then, if the user followed the warning given by said moderator and left, did the user get suspended?

Comment: The author of this answer either does not know that or is not willing to get involved in this.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade Let's not be disingenuous, please - you are the user this post is talking about, not someone else as this third person discourse might imply. You were suspended from Stack Overflow. Why I don't know - I'm not a moderator there. When I noticed you were chatting in an SO room, I said you should stop, and you did. No further action was taken - your chat account was not suspended. As far as I'm concerned this is a closed matter.

Comment: @ArtOfCode the user in question is banned on chat. Go look at their account there.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 Yup, I've just seen that. See [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46042308#46042308) - that chat suspension is down to a distinct issue, not because of this one.

Comment: @ArtOfCode  So the solution is to suspend the user from chatting everywhere?

Comment: @Muze Yes. Also, this post is old and dead, let's not resurrect it.